# I'm trying to display a list of documents from my model on my page index.html using angular

Tags: angularjs, spring

here's the content of my file app.js:

```
var app=angular.module("Doc",[]);
app.controller("DocController",function($scope,$http){
$scope.documents=[];
$http.get("/all")
 .success(function(data){
     $scope.documents=data;
 });

});
```

and my page index.html:

```
<body ng-app="Doc" ng-controller="DocController">
<table>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>REF</th><th>NAME</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr ng-repeat="k in documents">
    <td>{{k.dref}}</td>
    <td>{{k.dname}}</td> 
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript" src="angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
```

But when I run my app I don't get the list, It only displays this heads:
REf NAME 
like in my html page:

```
<th>REF</th><th>NAME</th>
```

Comment: Try to console data and see if your api is returning documents and if yes, in what format.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I did that and i found this error : "$http.get(...).success is not a function", then I found out that it was replaced by ".then" in angular recent versions,